# глобальная переменная

Tags: javascript

```
function fn() {
    dev = 'global';
    var dev = 'local';
    console.log(dev);
}

fn();
console.log(dev);
```

создаю глобальную переменную dev и локальную, внутри функции, почему ругается на "не определение" глобальной переменной? ведь если создам глобальную dev вне функции все будет окей и конфликтовать не будут

Comment: Все что определяется внутри функции без `window.varName` или `window['varName']` будет определено локально внутри блока функции.

Comment: если я напишу имя переменной другую, без var, то получится, что я создам новую глобальную переменную, так как же так?)

Comment: Если вы, определяете переменную внутри функции, без `var` или `let` или `const` - она все равно будет локальная и работать будет только в блоке функции. А вот если вы определите ее через `window` - то переменная станет глобальной и сможет работать за блоком функции и внутри функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fn() {
    dev = 'global';
    var dev = 'local';
    console.log(dev);
}
```

Эквивалентно:

```
function fn() {
    var dev;
    dev = 'global';
    dev = 'local';
    console.log(dev);
}
```

Так что переменная - локальная.